Stuck at try or install Ubuntu when trying to install Ubuntu 24.04 on VirtualBox 7
I am trying to run Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 LTS inside VirtualBox 7.0.20 on my Windows 11 PC. Virtualization is enabled. I’ve allocated 16GB RAMs, 6 CPUs, 64GB storage. I set graphics controller to VMSVGA, disabled 3D acceleration, set video memory to 128MB, and checked Hyper-V doesn’t exist.
Still, after selecting “Try or install Ubuntu” in GRUB, the system hangs with a black screen and a blinking underscore.
How can I fix this?

So, should we assume you have at the very least 32GB RAM and a 12-core CPU in the host system?

More than that, so yes.

If you're sure about that then try the option "Try... (safe graphics)".

@user15988 have you tried (at least for testing sake) using the default settings of Ubuntu install in VirtualBox with the default hardware settings and unattended installation?
